# How to create paint on the floor every time my Unity character dies?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, effect

[image]

red area in the image. The thing about my character dying in combat. Here's how to live paint on the floor when every character dies.
[image]

[image]

i tried this but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Define "doesnt work". Im going to guess it gets almost instantaneously removed as its likely parented to your character

Comment: can you explain a little more

Comment: **[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)**

Comment: @BugFinder from the code it doesn't look like parented to anything... `Instantiate` if not told different spawns objects at scene root level

Comment: Have you tried moving the two `Destroy` calls **after** trying to access the `transform.position`? ;) .. after you call `Destroy` this object is already marked as non-existent and you will get an error when trying to access `transform`

Answer (score 0):

The first part of code contains void RunTowardsTarget(). Do you call this void one time or every frame? It looks like you call it one time but there is if statement in this method so the condition will compare one time.
I think you need to use coroutine.

```
public IEnumerator RunTowardsTarget() 
{
    while(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetRunner.position) > 1)
    {
        targetRunner.position = targetRunner.position + speed;
        yield return null;
    }

    //your destroy calls
    onRunnerDied?.Invoke();
        
    Destroy(targetRunner.gameObject);
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```